# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\json_spirit\Debug\json_spirit_lib.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I'm not a C++ or VS developer but I'm trying to compile a project and I'm getting the above error.  I don't have any clue why the compiler is looking for that file or what the Debug folder is about (though I could guess).  Can somebody explain the issue in other words for me and give me some pointers on how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/JSON_Spirit.aspx speaks of two methods to link with the Json spirit library from c++.

I imagine your problem is that one or more of the header files includes a #pragma to automatically link certain libraries, the compiler can't find one of these libraries, namely json_spirit_lib.lib

This might be because of compiler level set up (default library directories); project set up (linker input and libray directories) or simply that you don't have the required .lib files in the source directories.